# python stack traces on login and after apt-get update

Tags: apt, bash, updates, bashrc

After my latest dist-upgrade, I'm now getting python stack traces on logging in/starting bash:

```
Last login: Wed Nov 28 19:33:57 2018 from x.x.x.x  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-i386-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_transfer_bindings
```

I should note that I'm using the stock .bashrc that came with Ubuntu; the only thing I've changed is adding aliases for my preferred "ls" switches.

I'm also getting similar errors when trying to run apt-get update:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):                
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-i386-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_transfer_bindings
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I tried `apt-get install --reinstall command-not-found` but to no avail. I'm rubbish at following stack traces and could use some help. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Python 3 setup?

Comment: Nope. This morning I tried reinstalling python 3.6 (which completed successfully; didn't fix the problem), but I haven't made any config changes.

Comment: Though I suppose Plex could have made changes on its own..

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I was running into the same undefined symbol trying to start sickbeard so I ran the following command as root:

```
scanelf -l -s sqlite3_transfer_bindings /lib/* /usr/* /opt/* | grep sqlite3_transfer_bindings
```

Which gave me this output:

```
ET_DYN sqlite3_transfer_bindings /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
ET_DYN sqlite3_transfer_bindings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

So I set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH for my sickbeard user to equal /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

And I was able to run sickbeard.

So presumably you can run the same command and then adjust your LD_LIBRARY_PATH value accordingly.

Comment: This worked (mostly)! I was having sudo-ing some of the plex commands a few days ago trying to force a media library update and messed with letting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This appears to be the root of all of my problems. I've got most of it fixed, but I'm still getting errors when I type a command that doesn't exist (command-not-found is definitely still broken).